# Writing a scope to display objects without associated objects - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am really struggling with SQL search queries today. Can one kindly tell me how i write a scope that display events with no payments.

```
event.rb
has_many :payments

payment.rb
belongs_to :event
```

i tried writing the below scope in the terminal:

```
events.joins(:payments).where("event.payments.empty?")
```

i also tried:

```
events.where("payments.empty?")
```

i am very unsure how to write a scope that displays an object with an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Event.includes(:payments).where(payments: { event_id: nil })
```

Comment: Glad to help you!